# Resharper custom inspection to create a new file

Tags: c#, resharper

I've been looking at this page describing how to create customised pattern-based replacements using Resharper: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Inspection__Creating_Custom_Inspections_and_QuickFixes.html

What I'd like to do though, is create a custom inspection which would allow a nested class MyClass.SubClass to be extracted to a new file by making the parent class (filename MyClass.cs) partial and move the nested class into a new file MyClass.SubClass.cs.

Semantically this ends up being the same code, just split between two files, what I'd like to know is if there is a way I could get Resharper to apply this refactoring automatically as an "Alt-Enter" action, in much the same way as in a file with two classes, you can Alt-Enter: "Move to new file"

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Move__Type_to_Another_File.html) from JetBrains seems to have your answer.

> If you invoke this refactoring on a nested type, ReSharper will make the parent class partial, create a new file for the new part of the partial class, and move the selected type there. If necessary, you can then use the Move Type to Outer Scope refactoring to make the type non-nested and simply remove the redundant part of the parent class.

You should use the "Move to Another File" refactor option.